# Why does bash sometimes think my $HOME isn't the correct directory?

Tags: macos, bash, ruby-on-rails, .bash-profile, rvm

Like the title says it seems that bash sometimes misidentifies my $HOME. This cropped up after a seemingly unique series of events that I will now replay in broad strokes.

- Running OS X 10.6 with normal, local account
- Work binds my account to Active Directory
- Much time passes with no issues
- Set up rvm to manage Ruby installs (this becomes important later)
- Upgraded to OS X 10.7 a few days ago
- After successful install, attempted to log in, was presented with "Must reset password" dialog that never allowed a password to be reset. Would simply shake the box after new password was entered.
- Much googling was done.
- Much more googling was done.
- Swearing was had.
- Logged in as root, created new account, set as admin, deleted /Users/[new account], renamed /Users/[old account] to /Users/[new account]
- Logged out of root, logged into new account with no issues

After OS X asking for a my account password a few times to update Keychain and other system-level stuff it was back to business as usual.

Opened Terminal, cd to project folder, tried "rails server" and was presented with:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in`to_spec'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
>       from /usr/local/bin/rails:18:in`'

Ran through a few exercises, decided to rm -rf ~/.rvm and reinstall. Running a --trace on the rvm installer shows it dies on this line:

> mkdir: /Users/[old account]: Permission denied

Scrolling back through the --trace log I see many more mentions of /Users/[old account]. When inspect the install script the offending line is looking at "${HOME}/.rvm" as it tries to run the mkdir. To my confusion I also see mentions of /Users/[new account] in the log.

I've tried exporting a new HOME in my .bash_profile to no luck.

Can anyone guess why /Users/[old account] would still be kicking around?

Comment: What does `dscl . -read /Users/$USER` (≥10.5) or `niutil -read . /users/$USER` (≤10.4) say your home is?  (Alternately, check Directory Utility.app (≥10.5) or NetInfo Manager.app (≤10.4).)

Comment: `dscl` reports home as `NFSHomeDirectory: /Users/adam`, which is what you would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem, although it's not the most elegant solution.

As rvm wouldn't run at all an `rvm implode` wasn't an option. Instead I just ran `rm -rf ~/.rvm` and reinstalled rvm.

It may be unrelated but I also had to download the [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) and set `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` before rvm and ruby builds would behave correctly. Using the `with-gcc=clang` did not provide usable builds.

Answer (score 0):

Something is clobbering your $HOME Variable.

Add this to your .bashrc file

```
 declare -x -r HOME=/correct/home/path
```